# valign="bottom" with CSS

Tags: html, css

Currently have a list of images in an unordered list.

```
<ul id="sponsors"><li><img src=.../></li>
<li><img src=.../></li><li><img src=.../></li>
</ul>
```

CSS for li tags are as follows:

```
float:left; margin:2px 4px; padding:0
```

Due to the different heights in my images, I wish to have them aligned to the bottom. I understand that this can be achieved easily with a table and ***valign="bottom"***. I have been playing around with ***vertical-align:bottom***  on the img tag and li tag but the attempts do not seem to align the images to the bottom.

How can I go about doing that ?

Comment: Can you put this on jsfiddle.net so that we all can fiddle it out?

Comment: definitely ! go to  http://jsfiddle.net/LhM9X/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `inline-block` to place the `li` elements side-by-side instead:

```
li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 2px 4px;
    padding: 0;
}
```

This assumes `li img` has the default `vertical-align` value of `baseline`. See it on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LHutF/1/

Answer (score 2):

In the styling for the `<li>` provided, the `float` property is being used. When floating an element, it is removed from the general flow of element layout on the page. This means that in your example, each `<li>` is actually floating outside of the borders of the unordered list containing them, and each is exactly the height and width of the image contained. In such a circumstance, the `vertical-align` property has nothing to align to bottom.

A simple example that demonstrates this issue follows. Please note that to simulate images of different heights, I have given each `<img>` a different `height` value (in CSS). In order to see what is truly happening during rendering, I have also added a border around each `<li>` and the `<ul>` tags.

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
    li { float:left; margin:2px 4px; padding:0; border: solid 1px black; }
    ul { border: solid 1px black; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <ul id="sponsors">
        <li><img style="height: 150px; width: 50px" src=.../></li>
        <li><img style="height: 50px; width: 50px" src=.../></li>
        <li><img style="height: 75px; width: 50px" src=.../></li>
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Hope this clarifies the issue.

you can try using `display: inline` on the `<li>` instead of floating them.

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
    ul { list-style: none; border: solid 1px black; }
    li { display: inline; border: solid 1px black; }
    img { vertical-align: bottom; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
   <ul id="sponsors">
      <li><img style="height: 150px; width: 50px" src=.../></li>
      <li><img style="height: 50px; width: 50px" src=.../></li>
      <li><img style="height: 75px; width: 50px" src=.../></li>
   </ul>
</body>
</html>
```